# Symfony2 accessing entity manager from elendev widget bundle

Tags: symfony

How to make doctrine connection available in a class loaded inside twig?
I am using the following 
https://github.com/Elendev/ElendevWidgetBundle

to create widgets, what i would need is access to the database global connection created in symfony.

In zend i would use Zend_Registry for example.

I am writing the widget like this:

```
<?php
namespace Test\Bundle\CommonBundle\Widget;
use Elendev\WidgetBundle\Annotation\Widget;

class Links {
    /**
    * @Widget(tag="links", priority=99)
    */
    public function links(){
        $twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(__DIR__."/views/")) );
        $links = new \Test\Bundle\CommonBundle\Entity\WidgetLinksData();
//how to i access entity manager from here?
        return $twig->render('links.html.twig', );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to inject the EntityManager
Your service definition probably look like this :

```
my_service:
    class: Test\Bundle\CommonBundle\Widget\Links
        # Add this 2 lines
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        tags:
            - {name: elendev.widget, method: memberDatas, tag: member_profile}
```

Then EntityManager instance will be loaded in your class constructor, so you just have to grab it :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Links
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

And you will be able to use it to do whatever you need in your class methods like this :

```
$this->em->find(...);
```

But injecting the EntityManager inside a twig extension isn't a "best practice", may should you use another service to wrap it.

For further information about dependency injection with symfony : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html